# Cómo se dice "tap and hold" en una pantalla táctil?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

Estoy tratando de traducir al español una aplicación para dispositivos táctiles que he desarrollado, y no puedo encontrar una traducción satisfactoria para la frase "touch and hold" o "tap and hold" para referirme a una acción sobre una pantalla táctil.

La única que he visto es "pulsar y mantener," pero no me gusta, me suena raro decir, "pulsa y mantén en una línea para cambiarla".

¿Hay algunas frases mejores que hayan visto ustedes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilizaría "mantén pulsado". Aglutina las dos propiedades de "touch/tap and hold": (1) pulsar y (2) mantener la pulsación.

Comment: Gracias! Por ejemplo, podría decir "mantén pulsado el botón verde para cambiar los ajustes" o "Puedes mantener pulsada un área vacía de la pantalla para abrir un menú."

Comment: @architectpianist Claro, es correcto.

Comment: @architectpianist Sí, suena bien!